# Get all functions and their parameters from a class

Tags: php, oop

I'm working on a plugin system for my CMS, to make the event registering system easy I need a function that can do the following.

I need to have a function that will return all functions from a specified class with the classes of their parameters. Of course, it's fine if the function to get the functions from a class and the function to get all the class names of the parameters of a function are different.

For example if you have the following class with these functions;

```
class MyClass {
    public function myFunction(Event $event) {
        // Function code
    }
}
```

It would be awesome if something like this could be returned;

```
Array() { 
    'myFunction' => Array() {
        0 => 'Event'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Tim Visée

Comment: nope. not standard.  could be a plugin/class that will add some functionality someway, but nothing out of the box.  The closest would be `get_defined_functions` and `get_declared_classes`, but that will not do what you are asking.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php ?

Comment: As @Diego Agulló answered, you can use the Reflection API which is exactly the thing I need, this is build in to PHP 5+ and my CMS required PHP 5.3.1 to run, so yes it seems to be possible with those functions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are exactly referring to the [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) API. Reflecting [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) or [methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) could lead you to do what you need. For example, try that:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$methods = $class->getMethods();

print_r($methods);

foreach ($methods as $method) {
    print_r($method->getParameters());
}
```

Comment: This looks great, I'll give it a try now! Thanks for the fast response btw.

Comment: This function works perfect, thank you very much! :)
Marked your answer as answer.